# Is there any advantage in using MockRestServiceServer over simply mocking a RestTemplate?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

In our code, we use Spring's RestTemplate to make an HTTP request and deserialize the response to a POJO.  That's it.  Any exceptions that might be thrown are propagated up and returned as an HTTP/500 response.  We don't take any action based on the response code of the RestTemplate call.

Question.  In our unit tests, is there any point in using MockRestServiceServer over simply mocking out our RestTemplate calls?

Answer (score 0):

For your given scenario using TestRestTemplate to mock all rest template calls should suffice. Make sure you are only mocking exact calls that should happen from the code and not mock a wider set of calls.